# iphone - how do I create a bundle and put files on it at run time

Tags: iphone

My app generates 3 files every time the user saves a project. I would like to be able to build a bundle at run time, and save all files to that bundle and save it to the app's directory. So if the user wants to move the project to the desktop its just the matter of dragging one bundle (= a directory that looks like a file, like the Mac OS X apps and Pages files)...

I googled around and found nothing.

How do I do that at run time?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundles are really just folder hierarchies conforming to a specific structure – see the [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1). You can use `NSFileManager` to create the folders in question, `NSPropertyListSerialization` to create the `Info.plist`, etc.

Comment: Remember though - It may look like a "bundle" on a Mac - but when you sync to a PC - it'll still just look like a folder.

Comment: thanks, I have read the guide you mentioned and I am now worst than before. What I need appears to be none of those examples (not an app bundle, not a framework bundle). I just need a bundle that can appear to be like a file to iOS and OSX and can be accessed like a directory as those of OSX. I am searching for a practical example.

Comment: @Brad - thanks. The bundle is meant to be used on OS X and iOS. I know it will appear like a folder on a PC, but there's not much I can do about it...

Comment: @Digital Robot Sorry, I should've linked you to the "Document Packages" section on that page, which describes more what you're talking about. Also check out `NSFileWrapper` for creating these kinds of bundles: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFileWrapper_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thanks, I will try do decipher the vague and enigmatic Apple docs.